# Should we use Azure Service Bus Queue built-in CorrelationId property or UserProperties?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-servicebus-queues

We're developing a Web API application that will receive a **correlation-id** header (GUID) in the request and will trigger a backend process asynchronously by sending a message to an Azure Service Bus Queue. We'd like to pass this correlation-id around for end to end monitoring purposes.

Should we use the **CorrelationId built-in property** or add a **CorrelationId user property** to UserProperties dictionary of the **Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Message**? What's the best practice?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `CorrelationId` property is there for convenience just like the `ContentType`, `To` or `ReplyTo` properties. They are typically used for various message patterns and unlike other system properties can be used without any concerns.

Short answer: use it rather than duplicating by introducing a custom property with identical intent.